# How to set the default user interface language in debian?

Tags: debian, locale

When I install the Debian, I choose the language to Chinese. After installation, I found that the menu is displayed in Chinese, even in the terminal the promote are written in Chinese.

I want the interface language change back to English, however it should not destroy my settings, eg. my input method, and when display Chinese characters, it will not display it as squares or some other random characters. Here is some locale output:

```
~$ env | grep LANG

LANG=en_US.UTF-8
GDM_LANG=zh_CN.utf8
LANGUAGE=zh_CN:zh


~$ locale -a

C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
zh_CN.utf8
```

In my `/etc/locale.gen` I commented off the `en_US.utf8` and `zh_CN.utf8`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the method described [here](https://wiki.debian.org/ChangeLanguage), and it works well. Not change my local time, my input method, even can display Chinese characters in terminal. Basically there are two steps:

1. `export LANG=es_US.UTF-8`
2. `dpkg-reconfigure locales`, in this step, deselect `zh_CN.UTF8`

reboot to see the effects.